# Is there an CSS feature to fit to the content of image?

Tags: css, image

[image: Fit to content]

I want to make an image to fit the content.
Trimming transparent background will be needed if it is done with a photo editor.

Is there any way to deal with CSS?
Or do I have to edit image before using it?

Thanks in advance!

What I have researched about css feature:

- object-fit: It was a little more about aspects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in CSS as far as I can tell.

However, there are two possible solutions fixing your problem.

**If it has to be done for an already known image:**

- You could manually scale the image using `background-size` and `background-position` so it does only show the area of the image you need.

**If it has to be done for an unknown image:**

- Using Javascript like this: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/683/how-to-remove-the-transparent-pixels-that-surrounds-a-canvas-in-javascript

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. This helps me very much and also gives me some hints for googling.  
  
**If it has to be done for an already known image:**
1) Is this the common way?  
2) Does this make the transparent area right-clickable by the user? (I don't want my surrounding canvas to be interactable)

Comment: if you use it as a background image, it is generally not right-clickable. However, if you would use it as a button, the transparent area would also be clickable.